# bonding fails on RedHat 7 while works on RedHat 6

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, bonding

What is the difference in bonding on Linux 7 versus Linux 6?
Note than I know there is also teaming available on Linux 7, but I am specifically looking for bonding.

I am doing bonding of two network interfaces on RedHat 7, and it causes an error:

```
bond0: An illegal loopback occurred on adapter (eth0)
Check the configuration to verify that all adapters are connected to 802.3ad compliant switch ports.
```

Note that I am running Linux as VM.

When doing exactly same steps that generate exactly same result (ifcfg-bond0, and changes to ifcfg-eth0, and ifcfg-eth1) all works fine.
On Linux 7, when I call `service network restart`, I am being disconnected for good, and I need to go the 'console' in order to fix the problem.

Here are my ifcfg-eth0, ifcfg-eth1 (the two one that I am bonding,) and ifcfg-bond0 files.

```
$>cat ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
IPADDR=10.12.3.33
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
MTU=1500
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 updelay=60000"

$>cat ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
#IPADDR=10.12.3.192
#NETMASK=255.255.255.0
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes

$>cat ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
#IPADDR=10.12.3.33
#NETMASK=255.255.255.0
MTU=1500
DHCP_HOSTNAME=
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

Here is the last line of the output when I am being disconnected:

```
Restarting network (via systemctl):
```

Comment: This is a VM. Are these NICs passed through (via PCI or similar) to the VM itself, or are they connected via a virtual switch or bridge? What hypervisor are you using?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M I have completely forgot about this question! We have found the reason for the problem, and disconnection is not caused by 802.3ad not compliant switch but because we had eth2 and iscsi configuration as well, and that was preventing network being restarted. When I gather details, time, and a bit of desire, I will put better explanation below. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ahhhh and that precludes bonding as it creates a MAC mask on the base interface (making the ARP magic impossible). Good find.